# If statements in Groovy Closures

Tags: groovy, closures

I am attempting to write a mini recursive closure to solve a parent children iteration. At a certain moment I need check if other children exists before I recursively call the closure. I do the check with an IF but for some reason the if returns always true.

**Updating the code with the objects that are included**

Have an Json object which has the structure Parent Children (referred as jsonArray in the code below)

```
   [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "No Children" //And yet the if condition is true -> element.children
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Does not like Children either"
    },
    {
        "id": "123",
        "name": "Some Parent Element",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "123123",
                "name": "NameWhatever"
            },
            {
                "id": "123123123",
                "name": "Element with Additional Children",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "123123123",
                        "name": "WhateverChildName"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "12112",
                        "name": "NameToMap"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

There is also an ArrayList object which has no IDs and need to retrieve them from the iteration in the jsonArray,
This is referred to as elementsToGetID which I am oversimplifying:

```
["count": 2741,"value": "NameToMap" ], ["count": 133,"value": "OtherName" ]
```

Thetwo for loops have been written time ago, and I am trying to write the recursive closure to go deeper into the children

```
for(int i=0; i<elementsToGetID.size(); i++){
    for(int j=0; j<jsonArray.size(); j++){

        { element ->
            if(element.name == elementsToGetID[i].value){
                elementsToGetID[i]["id"] = element.id
            }
            if (element.children) {
                element.children.each {inst ->
                    log.info "Element to continue function " +inst
                    call(inst) //This call fails
                }
            }
        }(jsonArray[j])

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give some example json structure so we can test it?

Comment: Hello @tim_yates . There is nothign special in the JSON example. Any structure parent children children will do for testing.

Comment: Your call(child.children) invokes the closure with a list of elements (multiple children), and not for one *child* at a time.

Comment: Ruben the recursive is not complete. This is an issue I still have to address. I need to navigate all children and check recursively. 


But the problem I have is that the "if condition" returns true even if the child (the one element being checked) returns true when it shouldn't (!?) whatever the condition.

Comment: Is this example could be self contained, so that we could reproduce it, that would be great.

Comment: Question has been updated to include examples of the variables used...

Comment: Can you define and externalize the closure outside the loop and just call it inside the loop?

Comment: hey @dmahapatro Thx for the info. I could but do not see any benefit and I need to reference the result object part of the loop as well. Any reason for your suggestion?

Comment: Reasoning added as an answer. :) I did not see you were using the part of loop in closure but my suggestion was exactly the same as my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the benefit. It works. :)

**Reason**
For recursion, a closure has to understand itself that it is defined before it is invoked.

```
def json = '''
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "No Children"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Does not like Children either"
    },
    {
        "id": "123",
        "name": "Some Parent Element",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "123123",
                "name": "NameWhatever"
            },
            {
                "id": "123123123",
                "name": "Element with Additional Children",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "123123123",
                        "name": "WhateverChildName"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "12112",
                        "name": "NameToMap"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
'''

def jsonArray = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
def elementsToGetID = [["count": 2741,"value": "NameToMap" ], 
                       ["count": 133,"value": "OtherName" ]]

//can be defined here as well
//def closure

for(int i=0; i < elementsToGetID.size(); i++){
    for(int j=0; j < jsonArray.size(); j++){
        def closure //defined locally

        closure = { element ->
            if(element.name == elementsToGetID[i].value){
                elementsToGetID[i]["id"] = element.id
            }
            if (element.children) {
                element.children.each {inst ->
                    closure(inst) //This call does not fail anymore
                }
            }
        }

        closure(jsonArray[j])
    }
}

assert elementsToGetID == [[count:2741, value:'NameToMap', id:'12112'], 
                           [count:133, value:'OtherName']]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can replace the multiple `for` loops in [dmahapatro's correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21707027/6509):

```
for(int i=0; i < elementsToGetID.size(); i++){
    for(int j=0; j < jsonArray.size(); j++){
        def closure //defined locally

        closure = { element ->
            if(element.name == elementsToGetID[i].value){
                elementsToGetID[i]["id"] = element.id
            }
            if (element.children) {
                element.children.each {inst ->
                    closure(inst) //This call does not fail anymore
                }
            }
        }

        closure(jsonArray[j])
    }
}
```

with this, to get the same result:

```
jsonArray.each { a ->
    elementsToGetID.find { a.name == it.value }?.id = a.id
    if( a.children ) {
        { -> a.children.each( owner ) }()
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems neat! Will give it a try. Thank you!

Comment: +1 Great. For OP: (If you are wondering what `owner` is): `owner` is the immediate parent closure of the anonymous closure used for recursion. In this case it is the closure used in `each`. @Armand